# Markup edit on photos disappeared, any way to recover it?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

So I had some pictures from school and I edited them in the Photos app on my Iphone 6S (latest software, done some updates in the meantime, maybe this could have caused my problem?) with markup, doing some important notes on them. A few weeks later, today, I wanted to take a look at them and I could not believe my eyes. The markups have disappeared, leaving me with the original photos with no notes on them. I can't imagine how something like this happened... Any way I can get my markups back? It would save me hours of work.

The photos are not backed up on my icloud because it's full...
Also, they worked in the past, this is not the first time I want to look at them since I edited them, they were fine some time ago.

Comment: Same thing happened to me today! Does someone have an answer?

Comment: I’ve faced the same problem! Did you find a solution to recover them?

Comment: sadly, no :( I had to write everything again...